# How to make file input stream ignore escape characters

Tags: java

Essentially i have this method that is supposed to read raw characters from a file and return them but something that i had'nt taken into account was the fact that it would add escape sequences to the returned string when it hit a return or the like in the file. For example if i have a text file with this in it

```
The dog is brown.
The dog is furry.
```

the method returns this

```
The dog is brown.\r\nThe dog is furry.
```

what i want it to return is

```
The dog is brown. The dog is furry.
```

I want when the input stream reads the escape \r to replace it with a space and when it reads \n to ignore it. Here is the method any help is appreciated.

```
public String getCharacters(File file, int number)  throws IOException {
         Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
          try {
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int count = 0;
            int intch;
            while (((intch = r.read()) != -1) && count < number) {
              resultBuilder.append((char) intch);
              count++;
            }
            return resultBuilder.toString();
          } finally {
            r.close();
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the characters you don't want, with the ones you do:

```
return resultBuilder.toString().replaceAll("\\r"," ").replaceAll("\\n","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all \n and \r,

```
return resultBuilder.toString().replaceAll("\\r|\\n"," ");
```